# Can't make readdir accept string var

Tags: php, string, readdir

Error: *readdir() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given*

```
$directorypremium = 'uploads/premium/'.text2url($pseudo_cookies).'/'; 

while($file = readdir($directorypremium)) {
        if($file != '.' AND $file != '..')
            {
            $taille_fichier = filesize($directory.$file); $taille_fichier = round($taille_fichier / 1000); $total_size = $total_size + $taille_fichier;
            }
        }
```

My function text2url:

```
function text2url($chaine)
    {
    $chaine = htmlentities($chaine, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8');
    $chaine = preg_replace('#\&([A-za-z])(?:uml|circ|tilde|acute|grave|cedil|ring)\;#', '\1', $chaine);
    $chaine = preg_replace('#\&([A-za-z]{2})(?:lig)\;#', '\1', $chaine);
    $chaine = preg_replace('#\&[^;]+\;#', '', $chaine);
    $chaine = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_ %\[\]\.\(\)%&-]/s', '', $chaine);
    $chaine = str_replace('(', '', $chaine);
    $chaine = str_replace(')', '', $chaine);
    $chaine = str_replace('[', '', $chaine);
    $chaine = str_replace(']', '', $chaine);
    $chaine = str_replace('.', '-', $chaine);
    $chaine = trim($chaine);
    $chaine = str_replace(' ', '_', $chaine);

    return $chaine;
    }
```

I know the problem is $chaine is a string value, but I cannot fix the problem to make it accept by readdir. Is there a way to make $chaine become valuable for the readdir function?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the person asking is unable to read the PHP manual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `readdir` function accepts a resource obtained from the `opendir` function:

```
$dir = opendir($path);
while($file = readdir($dir)){
...
```

See [readdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php)  and [opendir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php)

Comment: omg, I may removed opendir by mistake and completly forget about it... Thank you so much (both) for your help !

Answer (score 1):

[`readdir()`](http://php.net/readdir) accepts a **file handle**, not a string:

Quoting from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readdir.php):

> **dir_handle**:
>   The directory handle resource previously opened with `opendir()`. If the directory handle is not specified, the last link opened by `opendir()` is assumed.`

So perhaps use [`opendir()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opendir.php) first?